# Problema ao receber JSON muito grande em WebService RestFul

Tags: c#, web-service, restful

Trabalhamos aqui na empresa com Android + WebService (.Net RestFul) para a comunicação dos dados.

Estamos recebendo os dados em formato JSON em um método, segue abaixo:

```
//Método
public Retorno MetodoA(string sConexao, string sBanco, string sImeiDispositivo, List<Entidade> sJSON)

//Contrato
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/MetodoA/{sConexao}/{sBanco}/{sImeiDispositivo}",
            Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Retorno MetodoA(string sConexao, string sBanco, string sImeiDispositivo, List<Entidade> sJSON);
```

Até o momento estava funcionando normalmente, porém enviamos um JSON muito grande, e começou a apresentar um erro que não conseguimos encontrar ainda a solução.

Acredito que o problema esteja no web.config, mas não sei o que exatamente. Tenho no meu WebService um lugar onde estou passando o valor máximo e Buffer para envio e recebimento.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!-- AQUI -->
    <bindings>
      <!-- pick whichever binding you want .... -->
      <webHttpBinding>
        <!-- binding configuration with a name -->
        <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxBufferSize="2000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Esse é o erro que retorna:

> O servidor encontrou um erro ao processar a solicitação. Consulte os logs do servidor para obter mais detalhes

Porém esse erro só acontece quando os dados do JSON são muito grande.

O que pode ser?

Comment: Colocando esse código abaixo:

<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

Eu consegui ver que era um campo que estava com tipo diferente do recebido. Alterei e funcionou.

Obrigado.

Comment: Rafael, você pode responder sua própria pergunta e marcar como aceita.

Answer (score 1):

Colocando esse código abaixo no meu web.config, eu consegui ver que era um campo que estava com tipo diferente do recebido. Alterei o mesmo e funcionou.

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

Comment: Marquea como correta!

Comment: Estou aguardando o tempo que o fórum pede para depois disso fazer essa marcação. Obrigado.